# how to generate a new number for a random number guessing game in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

i'm hoping the title is self-explanatory, but for more context:
i wanna code a random number guessing game and instead of the game ending when the user guesses correctly, i ask the player if they'd like to play again and in the scenario where they answer yes, the code generates a new number and the game repeats.

this is the code:

```
# import time and random values
import random
import time


# tracks the number of attempts
attempts = 0

#introduction
print("welcome to my number guessing game! ")
input("press any key to start playing ")

while True:
# ask user for input
    number1 = random.randint(0,10)
    guess = int(input("guess a random number between 0 and 10. "))
    attempts += 1

# verify if guess is correct
    if guess == number1:
        playAgain = input(f"correct! the secret number was indeed {number1}, and you guessed it in {attempts} attempts. play again? (yes/no) ")
        if playAgain == "yes":
            # generate a new number and make the user try again
            number1 = random.randint(0,10) 
            continue
        else:
            break
    elif guess > number1:
        print("try a smaller number. ")
    else:
        print("try a bigger number. ")
```

instead of only generating a new number once the user guesses correctly and decides to play again, it generates a new number while the user is playing and so the game never really ends. how do i fix this?

Comment: move the first `number1 = random.randint(0,10)` before the `while`

Comment: @mozway - Just doing that doesn't make the game work as needed. Specifically, "the code generates a new number and the game repeats."

Comment: @not_speshal to be fair I haven't checked the whole thing. But it's an obvious first step in correcting it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change ur

```py
while True:
# ask user for input
    number1 = random.randint(0,10)
    guess = int(input("guess a random number between 0 and 10. "))
    attempts += 1
```

to

```py
while True:
    # Generate a new number for each game
    number1 = random.randint(0, 10)

    while True:
    # ask user for input
        guess = int(input("Guess a random number between 0 and 10: "))
        attempts += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variation of your existing code using a double `while` loop:

```
while True:
    #restart the game and generate number to guess
    number1 = random.randint(0,10)
    attempts  = 0
    
    guess = int(input("guess a random number between 0 and 10. "))
    attempts += 1
    
    #repeat this logic while the guess is not correct
    while guess!=number1:
        if guess > number1:
            print("try a smaller number. ")
        else:
            print("try a bigger number. ")
        guess = int(input("guess a random number between 0 and 10. "))
    
    #ask to continue once the previous game is completed
    playAgain = input(f"correct! the secret number was indeed {number1}, and you guessed it in {attempts} attempts. play again? (yes/no)")
    if playAgain == "no":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `number1 = random.randint(0,10)` is within your `while-loop`

Place your first `number1 = random.randint(0,10)` above the while loop and also set your attempts back to 0 when they say yes to playing again.

The way you have it will make it so that every time the user guesses, it will be a freshly generated number (not intended).

Here is the fixed code:

```
import random
import time

# tracks the number of attempts
attempts = 0

# introduction
print("Welcome to my number guessing game!")
input("Press any key to start playing ")

# Generate the random number outside the loop
number1 = random.randint(0, 10)

while True:
    # ask user for input
    guess = int(input("Guess a random number between 0 and 10. "))
    attempts += 1

    # verify if guess is correct
    if guess == number1:
        playAgain = input(f"Correct! The secret number was indeed {number1}, and you guessed it in {attempts} attempts. Play again? (yes/no) ")
        if playAgain == "yes":
            # reset attempts and generate a new number
            attempts = 0
            number1 = random.randint(0, 10)
        else:
            break
    elif guess > number1:
        print("Try a smaller number.")
    else:
        print("Try a bigger number.")
```